# Get Count of DataSet.Tables rows based on criteria

Tags: c#, datatable

The code below is returning a value of 0 every time. I am trying to filter a datatable and get the number of rows. To illustrate the example here, I am setting the criteria as the value 250 to be looked for in my ID column in Table2.

How can I fix it?

```
var count = (from row in MyDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Table2"].AsEnumerable() where string.Equals(row["ID"].ToString(), 250)) select row).Count();
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(count));
```

Comment: Is `MyDatabaseDataSet` your DataSet type or and instance of it?

Comment: An instance of it. It is a database that is attached to the project already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With method syntax:

```
int rowCount = MyDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Table2"].AsEnumerable()
    .Count(r => r.Field<int>("ID") == 250);
```

Comment: @SimonTouyet: Then there are no ID's with 250 ;-)

Comment: there's definetely an item with ID 250 :)

Answer (score 3):

Try that one:

```
var count = (from row in MyDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Table2"].AsEnumerable()
             where row.Field<int>("ID") == 250
             select row).Count();
```

Comment: Still no luck. gives my 0 as a result still

Answer (score 0):

Ok emmmmmmm well this is... awkward... I absolutely forgot to fill the dataset with the second table before calling the code. Here's what I had forgotten:

```
// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'showsDatabaseDataSet.AllEpisodes' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.MyTableAdapter.Fill(this.MyDatabaseDataSet.Table2);
```

It is now working thanks guys!